# Cast str[str.size()-1] as interger in c++?

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, integer

I have no idea how to cast `str[str.size()-2]` and `str[str.size()-1]` as integers. I need to return answers as integers.

```cpp
int main()
{
    cin>>D;
    int k;
    int z;
    int*tab=new int [D];
    for (int i=0;i<D;i++)
    {
        cin>>tab[i];    
    }
    
    for (int i=0;i<D;i++)
    {
        z=silnia(tab[i]);
        string str = to_string(z);
        if (str.size()>1)
            cout<<str[str.size()-2]<<" "<<str[str.size()-1];
        else
            cout<<"0 "<<str[0];
        cout<<endl;
        suma=1;
    }    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "convert `str[str.size()-2]` and `str[str.size()-1]` to `int`"? They are already characters representing digits and should be printed as digits.

Comment: When you say "return answers as number", what do you mean by *return*? Just to print? Because that's what you're already doing.

Comment: once you print on the screen there is no difference between `1` and `'1'`

Comment: please include input, output and expected output in the question. currently it is not clear what the problem with your code is

Comment: I need to print numbers of tens and singular numbers of some number. With this solution judge in spol don't accept string as answer.

Comment: #include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int suma=1;
int D;
int silnia(int n)
{
    while(n>1)
    {

        suma=suma*n*(n-1);
        n=(n-2);
    }

};

Comment: Printing the string `"10"` is no different from printing the integer `10`. There is no difference in the output. Try doing e.g. `cout << 10 << "10"` and see the non-difference yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `substr` and `atoi`.

> `string std::string::substr (size_t pos = 0, size_t len = npos) const;`
> Generate substring
> Returns a newly constructed string object with its value initialized to a copy of a substring of this object. The substring is the portion of the object that starts at character position pos and spans len characters (or until the end of the string, whichever comes first).
> http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

> `int atoi (const char * str);`
> Convert string to integer
> Parses the C-string str interpreting its content as an integral number, which is returned as a value of type int.
> http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/

Answer (score 0):

you can include sstream library then simply do the following:

```
stringstream a(str[str.size()-2]);
int x;
a >> x;
```

now x has the value of whatever ur string was and you can freely return x